# Feynrules -> FeynArts issue

Tags: packages, physics

When I try to use model files generated by `FeynRules` in `FeynArts`, I always get errors of this form

> Coupling definition in model file for `C[S[5],S[1,{e2x1}],-V[3]]` is \
>   incompatible to generic coupling structure. Coupling is not a vector \
>   of length 1.

(when I use the `InsertField` function, `InsertFields[t11, {S[7], -S[7]} -> {S[2], S[2]}, Model -> "NMSSM"]`, etc.)

I have tried using the `SM` and `NMSSM` models included with `FeynRules`, and my own models and I get the same error. When I tried using the `SM` model file that's included with `FeynArts`, there's no problem. So it seems there's a problem with the `FeynArts` model files generated by `FeynRules`?

I'm using `FeynRules` 2.0.3 and `FeynArts` 3.9.

Answer (score 8):

You did not load the generic model:

```
InsertFields[t11, {S[7], -S[7]} -> {S[2], S[2]}, Model -> "NMSSM"]
```

should be replaced with

```
InsertFields[t11, {S[7], -S[7]} -> {S[2], S[2]}, Model -> "NMSSM", GenericModel -> "NMSSM"]
```

The `Model` option loads `NMSSM.mod`, the `GenericModel` loads `NMSSM.gen`.